# C++ pointer to map->second not pointing

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

Disclaimer: I'm new to C++ (a student) and this is for assessment in a computer prac, so please don't give me the answer. If you could 'guide' me to the answer, to help my understanding, that would be much appreciated.

So, I have a map:

```
std::map<std::string,MyClass> mymap;
```

and I have an iterator that goes over this map and does stuff (that I wrote):

```
MyClass *retVal;
for (auto m : mymap) 
{
    if (m.count() == 0)
        *retVal = m.second;
}

return *retVal;
```

I can't just return `m.second` so I need to work out how to get *retVal to point to the reference of m.second, not the value.

I thought I had it, but the debugger says otherwise.

I tried adding `&m.second` but the compiler didn't like that.

I even tried

```
for(<std::map<std::string,MyClass>::iterator myIter = mymap.begin(); myIter != tasks.cend(); ++myIter)
```

with changing all the `.second` to `->second`, but again, no joy.

I'm really hitting a brick wall how to fix this.. any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "compiler didn't like that"-post the actual error and we may be able to help. The function footprint Though my guess is that your function footprint is `MyClass foo()`, which is returning the class by value. If you want to return it by reference, return either a `MyClass&` or a `MyClass*`, but in either case ownership can get weird.

Comment: SO is not for guiding. This isn't a mentoring service. It's a repository of questions and answers for the ages. You should discuss with a tutor or friend, or in a chatroom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need a reference, not a copy, to the map element:

```
for (auto & m : mymap)
          ^
```

Then use the `&` (*address of*) operator to get a pointer to its value:

```
retVal = &m.second;
         ^
```

Notice that this is assigning the pointer (`retVal`), not the object that it points to (`*retVal`). Assigning the object would be wrong, since it doesn't point to a valid object.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mike. So once I declare retVal as a pointer *retVal, I don't need `*retVal =` ever again? Also, the & makes sense! thank you very much!

Comment: @destro Probably not in this function, though you will have to do it sometime...`*retVal = ` will set what the value points to to that value. If you need to copy a class to a memory location, then you will do this. If you're not using smart pointers, you'll probably end up doing this sometime.

Comment: @destro: Use `*retVal = ...` if the pointer already points to an object, and you want to change the value of that object, leaving the pointer still pointing to it. Use `retVal = ...` if you want to make the pointer point to the object that `pointer` points to, without changing the object.